# when a browser parses a PHP file (containing JavaScript), which language parses first, PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm confused about this question. Actually I'm trying to get a JavaScript value to PHP variable using Ajax, but I'm getting error. I think that PHP is parssing first before I could put the value to it via JavaScript

Comment: A browser never gets access to a PHP file.

Comment: What you think is correct. When a browser loads a page, PHP coding are phrased first.

Comment: I think the desired word is "parsing" not "phrasing", the latter referring to how sentences are structured rather than to programming.

Answer (score 5):

PHP is serverside means it runs on the server, when you get your page php already run through is finished and made his output and then JS starts to work on your computer (clientside).  ;)

Answer (score 2):

The PHP is interpreted first on the server and the result is rendered to HTML and JavaScript as appropriate. When the client browser receives this result it will run any embedded scripts, including JavaScript. You also mentioned AJAX, which is a specific usage of JavaScript that makes a connection back to the server from the browser. An AJAX call is sometimes used to bring the value of a server side (possibly PHP) variable into JavaScript after the initial page contents have been sent to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is parsed on server side, JS is parsed in browser. So, when client asks for a page, at first server runs PHP script to the end, generates HTML and puts it into browser, where JS starts runing.